# Resize WinXP32 QEMU virtual machine always causes disk read error / OS load error on boot

Tags: resize, windows-xp, fedora, qemu

Fedora 27 x86_64.

I have a WinXP32 qemu virtual machine that works fine, but I want to increase the disk size.

I have Googled extensively and followed several sets of instructions for resizing, using both qemu-img and virt-resize. In every case, booting the new vm itself works, but results in Windows reporting either "Disk read error" or "Error loading operating system".

I can create a new empty qemu vm of the desired size, but that is not much use as I do not know how to transfer my content from the old vm to the new.

Am I doing something stupid? Is there another tool I should be using?

Comment: Do you do anything else after resizing the virtual disk image itself, like resizing the partitions?

Comment: **Thanks for replying Blender.** One set of guides I followed is at [this location](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107228/how-to-resize-virtual-machine-disk/481887). It says not to expand the boot partition, but I have no choice as my WinXP vm has only one partition - this must be my problem I guess. Dang it. I think my strategy must be to create a new empty vm of the size I want, install XP, then laboriously copy all my files. Sigh.

Comment: You may have better lucking just resizing the virtual disk image (i.e.  making the entire hard drive itself bigger but leaving the data intact) and then booting into some other Windows-specific tool to resize your primary partition.

Comment: I would prefer to do exactly that, but I can't boot the resized vm at all. I am currently wrestling with WinXP's wizard to transfer my files from the old vm to a new bigger one I have just created. I only use one program in WinXP and it runs on Fedora with only one (vital) feature not working. (Sound of head beating against wall). WOuld love to get rid of XP.

Comment: In that case, you might be able to run in in Fedora with Wine (stable, development, or [staging](https://wine-staging.com/)).

Comment: Yes, it is under Wine and performs faultlessly apart from the minor issue of being unable to update its data files. If I could solve that, all would be well.